# Azure service bus - delayed queue message java sdk

Tags: java, azure, message-queue, azureservicebus

I am trying to set delayed message in azure service bus queues.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.scheduledenqueuetimeutc.aspx

I have the below java code

```
 ServiceBusContract serviceBus = ServiceBusService.create(ServiceBusConfiguration
            .configureWithWrapAuthentication(env.getSERVICEBUS_NS(), env.getSERVICEBUS_OWNER(),
                    env.getSERVICEBUS_KEY(), ".servicebus.windows.net",
                    "-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9")) 
 BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(inputStream);
 Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
 instance.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
 brokeredMessage.setScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc(instance.getTime());
 serviceBus.sendQueueMessage("queueName", brokeredMessage);
```

I am expecting the message to be en-queued in one minute delay, but it en-queued right away.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other properties to set? maybe special queue properties? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to increase the delay to see if it continues to happen? Are the clocks syncronized?